# Is it possible to "bump" a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, bumping

Hello,

I recently asked a question asking for the help of the community in my preparation for grad school. However, I only got one answer to the question and I fear it has now faded into oblivion. Is it somehow possible to "bump" the question somehow? If not to get more answers, to simply get some feedback to improve this sort of question for next time?

Thanks!

Comment: lol "bump" is 4chan terminology. anyhow, editing it would get it on top. though there are limits to that i believe.

Comment: "Bump" is pretty standard forum terminology.

Comment: Is that an answer to the question, @MartinSleziak?

Comment: @T.Bongers: It *is* a meta site, so meta-answers are generally better than answers, no? :-)

Comment: Notice how Martin bumped this question?

Comment: The answers to this question might have some useful information related to this topic: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

1. You can "bump" your thread by **providing status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself**. I usually do that unless I really hit a dead end with no further clues to follow. Some times I eventually bring about enough understanding to realise the answer, and thus post a resolution to my own problem.
2. If you have [at least **75** rep points](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties), you can offer a **bounty**, promising to give some of your points to the person who correctly answers your question.

Comment: thanks I'll try that!