# Is double posting allowed if a question is not answered after some time?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I've asked questions in the past that have gone unanswered or have not had sufficient answers, would it be unethical to repost my questions to try to get an answer another time?

Comment: Generally this is frowned upon as it clutters up the site with duplicates. Refer to this post here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1907/is-it-possible-to-bump-a-question. In general it seems the best practice is to offer a bounty, once you have more than 75 rep. Failing that, you can edit the post to offer some more of your progress or thoughts - which would bump it.

Comment: I have found that making an edit to a post can garner quite a bit of new attention, whether it be a question or an answer.  Add tags, improve spelling / grammar / clarity, and/or provide extra context, progress, etc.  Adding a tag in particular can be crucial since, for example, I pay attention almost exclusively to questions highlighted blue in the list (i.e. they have a tag I have "favorited").  Even if your post is something super specific with field theory, or the theory of integration, throw an "abstract algebra" or "calculus" tag in there, and people like me are more likely to notice.

Comment: Adding to my previous post: I have been using this site long enough to strongly suspect that there's a small but nontrivial fraction of users who search through MSE by a given tag *specifically* on a regular basis, as opposed to sifting through the list of new or active posts.    Just another reason to add as many tags as are relevant.

Comment: @KajHansen that is definitely not wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Posting the same question anew just to get more attention is not acceptable behavior. Please do not do this.

If it is noticed your questions will be swiftly closed as a duplicate, likely it will also be downvoted and usually some users will complain.

For acceptable ways to draw attention to existing questions see [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question) (although one suggestion, namely to edit, may have been more effective when that answer had been written then it is now.)

Comment: If the original question had no upvoted answers, then the repeat can't be closed as a duplicate, can it? But everything else you write in this answer is certainly true.

Comment: In general you are right, but in this particular context it actually can be closed, as it is about [a repost by the same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165852/duplicate-question-changes-cant-mark-duplicates-by-same-user).