# What can I do to get a quick answer?

Tags: support

Usually if I write a Question it will be answered within one hour or not at all, that' why I want to start a Bounty - it would help me to draw Attention to my Question and would also be an incentive to get a **quick** reply. But since this is not an Option (I have to wait two days) - I am asking you for other suggestions.

Comment: Learn patience and that quick answers are not up to you. Or any answer, for that matter.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to “bump” a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1907). However, SE is never meant to get a quick answer to a problem.

Comment: Mostly when someone here wants a quick answer, it is because their homework is due and they want us to do it for them.  I vote against making that easier than it already is.

Comment: The way to get a quick answer is to hire a mathematical consultant. Plenty of talented mathematicians out there looking for a good way to earn some spare cash.

Comment: If it's difficult enough to deserve a bounty, it's probably difficult enough to requure some thinking time! I'd rather have an accurate, well thought-out answer than a quick non-answer or wrong answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)  Ask a [good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), so you can avoid closure of the question, and provide sufficient context that makes your question clear and fully answerable in one answer.

(2) As @AsafKaragila suggests: "Learn patience and that quick answers are not up to you. Or any answer, for that matter."

(3)  Don't wait until *your* last minute to ask a question.  E.g., if you have a question from a test or assignment due on Monday, don't wait until Sunday to ask your question.  Plan ahead, meaning work through homework/test questions so that you've been able to address all of them,  a few days prior to Monday, or whenever it is due, and ask questions early enough when you are stuck, so that getting "quick answers" is no longer in need, and so questions asked at the last minute aren't in "urgent" and in need of being answered *ASAP.*

(4) Finally, the goal of getting a "quick answer" is rather ambiguous and rather subjective. It is likely (as per (2)), that you may have an unreasonable expectation as to what counts as getting a "quick answer."  Every answerer on this site, including all site moderators, are volunteering their time and efforts, when helping others.  It is rather presumptuous to think there is someone at hand, at every and any hour, to answer last-minute questions, instantly.  If you'd like that sort of attention, you are free to hire a tutor that will always be "on-call" to answer any and every one of your last minute questions.  Be prepared to pay a lot of money for such a service.

In short, math.se doesn't promise "quick answers" to all questions.  That is not *our* job.  Rather, it is *your* job to ask questions well in advance of when you have homework due, or a take-home test is due.

Answer (score 3):

When you want something, you have three choices.

- Quick and cheap, not accurate
- Quick and accurate, not cheap
- Accurate and cheap, not quick

Stack Exchange is free to the user, and has minimum quality standards. That immediately excludes the first two points.

If you want one of them instead, use Quora or Reddit, or hire a tutor.